# Ужимание родителя под размер дочернего элемента

Tags: html, css

У меня код представляет идею стола с полароидными фотокарточками в изометрическом представлении.

[Архив с фрагментом проекта](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T3wQE_iX8c3ONRyDjHRMMAjpTE6TN3O8/view?usp=sharing)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Table</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    div.table {
      max-width: 700px;
      transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg) scaleY(0.86062);
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    div.table_flex {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: stretch;
    }
    div.table_flex div {
      display: inline-block;
      max-width: 200px;
      max-height: 200px;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 0.7px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    div.table_flex div img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table table_flex">
    <div><img src="img/stab II StG 77.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/octocat.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/flag-belarus.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Изображения вы можете найти в [архиве](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T3wQE_iX8c3ONRyDjHRMMAjpTE6TN3O8/view?usp=sharing) или подставить свои.

**И так, вопрос:** как заставить div'ы ужиматься под размеры содержимого как по вертикали, так и по горизонтали?

Comment: У Вас для изображений внутри этих самых div`ов заданы размеры = 100% от родительского. И теперь Вы хотите, чтобы этот самый родитель ужимался под размеры дочернего изображения. Стоит определиться, кто под кого будет подстраиваться.

Comment: @hisbvdis Окей, указывая максимальный размер изображения в абсолютных еденицах, наш div ужимается по ширине, а как на счёт высоты? **CSS-код:** div.table_flex div { display: inline-block; box-sizing: content-box; margin: 5px; border: 0.7px solid black; padding: 5px; padding-bottom: 15px; } div.table_flex div img { max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px; }

Answer (score 0):

Не для изображений размеры задавайте, а ширину для родительских `div`, а изображениям `width: 100%;`

Изображение по ширине будет занимать всю ширину блока, а высота блока будет автоматически заканчиваться там, где высота изображения.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что во flex'е надо как-то иначе задавать размерности...